# View not showing content after upgrade from D6 to D7

Tags: 7, views, upgrading

I am new to drupal.  I have just upgraded from version 6 to version 7.  I have all my template files moved from the old version and the database is operational.

I have a view that is showing the header but the rest of the view is not visible.  I can go into views and preview and everything looks fine.

Here is my view:

```
    <div id="dehumidifiers" class="<?php print $classes; ?> block block-views">
   <h2>Dehumidifiers</h2>
   <?php if ($admin_links): ?>
    <div class="views-admin-links views-hide">
  <?php print $admin_links; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($header): ?>
<div class="view-header">
  <?php print $header; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($exposed): ?>
<div class="view-filters">
  <?php print $exposed; ?>  
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($attachment_before): ?>
<div class="attachment attachment-before">
  <?php print $attachment_before; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($rows): ?>
<div class="view-content">
  <?php print $rows; ?>
</div>
<?php elseif ($empty): ?>
<div class="view-empty">
  <?php print $empty; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($pager): ?>
<?php print $pager; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($attachment_after): ?>
<div class="attachment attachment-after">
  <?php print $attachment_after; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($more): ?>
<?php print $more; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($footer): ?>
<div class="view-footer">
  <?php print $footer; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($feed_icon): ?>
<div class="feed-icon">
  <?php print $feed_icon; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

</div> <?php /* class view */ ?>
```

Like I said, I am new to drupal and need some assistance on where to go from here.  Everything worked great in D6.

Not sure if this would be helpful but, here is my block.tpl.php file.

```
  <?php
     // $Id: block.tpl.php,v 1.3 2007/08/07 08:39:36 goba Exp $
  ?>
 <?php if($block->subject == "#clean_output#"){
           print $content;
        } else { ?>
        <!-- Check if Block is in right sidebar -->
     <? $sidebartext = $block->delta;?>
     <? if (strpos($sidebartext, "sidebar_test")){?>
     <? //if there is no content
   if (!strpos($block->content, "sorry")){?>        
    <?php if ($block->region == 'right'){ echo '<div class="sidebar">';} ?>
    <? //use this session to make sure the collapse is in sequence
       if ($_SESSION['testdoc']==""){$_SESSION['testdoc']=1;}
        else{$_SESSION['testdoc'] = $_SESSION['testdoc']+1;}?>
    <div id="block-<?php print $block->module .'-'?>block-views-document_sidebar_test-block_<?=$_SESSION['testdoc']?>" class="clearfix block block-<?php print $block->module ?>">   
        <div id="block-views-document_sidebar_test-block_<?=$_SESSION['testdoc']?>" class="CollapsiblePanel">
            <div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0"><?php print $block->subject ?></div>
            <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">
                <div class="content" id=""><?php print $block->content ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var CollapsiblePanel<?=$_SESSION['testdoc']?> = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("block-views-document_sidebar_test-block_<?=$_SESSION['testdoc']?>" , {contentIsOpen:false});
    </script>

    <?php if ($block->region == 'right'){ echo '</div>';} ?>

<? }//end of if there is content?>  

  <? }else{
 if ($block->region == 'right'){ echo '<div class="sidebar">';} 
    $tttid = $block->delta;
    //echo $tttid."-----";
    if ($tttid<>37){ //don't show the block div on facebook block?>
        <div id="block-<?php print $block->module .'-'. $block->delta; ?>" class="clearfix block block-<?php print $block->module ?>">
    <? }?>
    <?php if (!empty($block->subject)): ?>
        <h2><?php print $block->subject ?></h2>
    <?php endif;?>

    <? if ($tttid<>37){?><div class="content"><? }?>
        <?php print $content?>
    <? if ($tttid<>37){ //don't show the block div on facebook block?>
        </div><!--end of content div-->
     </div><!--end of bloc div-->
    <? }?>
  <?php if ($block->region == 'right'){ echo '</div>';} ?>

   <? }?>

  <?php } ?>
```

Here is also my nodes.tpl.php

```
<?php
// $Id: node.tpl.php,v 1.5 2007/10/11 09:51:29 goba Exp $
?>
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="node<?php if ($sticky) { print ' sticky'; } ?><?php if (!$status) { print ' node-unpublished'; } ?>">

<?php print $picture ?>

<?php if ($page == 0): ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $title ?>"><?php print $title ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($submitted): ?>
  <span class="submitted"><?php //print $submitted; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

 <div class="content clearfix">
  <?php print $content ?>
  <? //get the url to see if this is the model specification
  $urltmp = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $endurl = end($urltmp);
  if ($endurl =="model-specifications"){?>
    Click model number for detailed specifications.
 <? }?>
  <?php print render( $page['skus'] ); ?>

 </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
   <div class="meta">
   <?php if ($content): ?>
     <div class="terms"><?php print render( $page['terms'] ); ?></div>
   <?php endif;?>
   </div>

   <?php if ($links): ?>
      <div class="links"><?php print render( $page['links'] ); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a cache issue?  Typically whenever I have problems like this I'll always go and clear the cache first to see if that fixes it, kind of like restarting the computer when I'm experience strange behavior in my running programs.

Comment: I have cleared the cache and restarted the computer.

Comment: still not working after multiple cache clearing and restarts.